# Azure Custom Domain (Namecheap) not working without www

Tags: azure, dns

I thought I had all my mappings perfectly done:

[image]

I'm able to add the www.mydomain.me to azure but not mydomain.me. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: When I attempt to point to mydomain.me in my broswer, I get the following error message:

```
Error 404 - Web app not found.

The web app you have attempted to reach is not available in this Microsoft Azure App Service region. This could be due to one of several reasons:

1. The web app owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure App Service, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it. Click here to read more.

2. The web app owner has moved the web app to a different region, but the DNS cache is still directing to the old IP Address that was used in the previous region. Click here to read more.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's wrong since you've hidden the settings.  Here's what should work:

- **A Record** points to the IP address found on the Azure portal
- **CName** *awverify* points to awverify.yourservice.azurewebsites.net
- **CName** *www* points to yourservice.azurewebsites.net

Comment: @ do you mean literally just "www" and just "awverify" as hostnames?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: that and I was missing an @ host to point to the azure site. Thanks a mill

Comment: I have all these set up and I am still getting the issue

Comment: I set up but it didn't work and then I delete the custom domain and set up again with an SSL binding and restarted the app. After some seconds it's ok. Now it works fine.